# AutoMapper how to resolve using calculated fields

Tags: automapper

How does one perform Business Logic along with AutoMapper?

e.g I have a field named "CalculatedField" and it is calculated from FirstName + LastName plus their Email.

example of the code

```
if (firstName != null)
   CalculatedField += firstName;
if (lastName != null)
   CalculatedField += lastName;
if (email != null)
   CalculatedField += email;
```

Comment: See [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html). But you'll have to decide what's mapping logic and what's business logic. Using AutoMapper for simple things is alright, but business logic per se belongs in your own classes, not in the AM configuration.

Comment: Thanks.  It worked out well